# Preserve initialization order when converting object to dict?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to preserve the order of the initialization of a python class, similar to how you might think of fields of a struct in C.

```
import struct
from collections import OrderedDict

class MyClass(OrderedDict):
     PACKET_FORMAT = '<BBB'
     def __init__(self, packet):
         super(MyClass, self).__init__()
         (a, b, c) = struct.unpack(self.PACKET_FORMAT, packet)
         self.a = a
         self.b = b
         self.c = c

mc = MyClass(bytearray([0x01, 0x02, 0x03]))
print(mc.__dict__)
```

I thought `OrderedDict` would be relevant here, but it appears not.  My order isn't being preserved:

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

I expected/want:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```